# Silverlight Grid loaded but does not show data

Tags: datagrid, silverlight-4.0

I have a silverlight form where in i am populating a datagrid in the constructor of the form, below is the code...

```
public partial class ManageArtists : UserControl
{
    ChinookDomainContext cdContext = new ChinookDomainContext();

    public ManageArtists()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        cdContext.Load(cdContext.GetArtistsQuery());

        dpArtistPager.Source = cdContext.Artists.OrderBy(artist => artist.Name);
        dgArtistList.ItemsSource = cdContext.Artists.OrderBy(artist => artist.Name);
    }
}
```

Now the problem is....Even though the data is loaded in the grid it does not show anything until i click on the Header fields of the grid. I dont understand why is this happening ??

can someone explain me whats happening !!

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line -

```
dgArtistList.ItemsSource = cdContext.Artists.OrderBy(artist => artist.Name);
```

you'll find that your `ItemsSource` is being set to an instance of `IOrderedEnumerable`,..which doesn't support property changed notification.

To fix this quickly and easily wrap that collection in an `ObservableCollection` and your data should display correctly.

HTH